# Why my service always return NULL in implementation class?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

Can someone help me I am stuck trying to implement `Rabbitmq` with `Spring` but my service doesn't works!

```
public class QueWorker implements MessageListener {

    @Inject/@Autowired not working T-T
    private CsvService csvService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // System.out.println(new String(message.getBody()));
        Gson gsonGet = new Gson();
        TypeToken<Map> json = new TypeToken<Map>() {};
        Map msgGet = gsonGet.fromJson(new String(message.getBody()), json.getType());
        Map data = (Map) msgGet.get("data");
        ArrayList containerData = (ArrayList) msgGet.get("containerData");
        try {
            csvService.excutePermit(containerData, data);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How you instanciate `QueWorker`? Autowiring only works in spring managed beans, not if you create the class with `new` keyword

Comment: Yes i have initiate QueWorker in QueConfig

Answer (score 1):

Im found work around to solve this problem by creating AutowireHelper.java and AutowireHelperConfig.java

Put it under spring config folder > util

> AutowireHelper.java

```
package com.yourcompany.yourapplicationname.config.util;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

/**
 * Helper class which is able to autowire a specified class.
 * It holds a static reference to the {@link org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext}.
 */
public final class AutowireHelper implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final AutowireHelper INSTANCE = new AutowireHelper();
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    AutowireHelper() {
    }

    /**
     * Tries to autowire the specified instance of the class if one of the specified beans which need to be autowired
     * are null.
     *
     * @param classToAutowire the instance of the class which holds @Autowire annotations
     * @param beansToAutowireInClass the beans which have the @Autowire annotation in the specified {#classToAutowire}
     */
    public static void autowire(Object classToAutowire, Object... beansToAutowireInClass) {
        for (Object bean : beansToAutowireInClass) {
            if (bean == null) {
                applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(classToAutowire);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AutowireHelper.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * @return the singleton instance.
     */
    public static AutowireHelper getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

> AutowireHelperConfig.java

```
package com.yourcompany.yourapplicationname.config.util;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * configuration class to create an AutowireHelper bean
 */
@Configuration
public class AutowireHelperConfig {
    @Bean
    public AutowireHelper autowireHelper(){
        return new AutowireHelper();
    }

}
```

> Call service in implement class without getting NULL **Autowire your Service** then call it with **AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.csvService)** see example below !

```
public class QueWorker implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private CsvService csvService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        Map msgGet = (Map) SerializationUtils.deserialize(message.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> data = (Map) msgGet.get("data");
        ArrayList containerData =  new ArrayList((Collection) msgGet.get("containerData"));
        try {
            AutowireHelper.autowire(this, this.csvService);
            csvService.excutePermit(containerData, data);
            System.out.println(" [x] Received Message'");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println(" [x] Done Process Message'");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must annotate CsvService class with some Spring component (example @Service).

```
@Service
public class CsvService  {
 //Code Here
}
```

And

```
public class QueWorker implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired 
    private CsvService csvService;
}
```

If you have already done that and still it does not work, this must not be visible to spring in class path scan. In your Spring applicatgion main, you need to add

```
@ComponentScan(basePackage="")
```

Add your package name.

Comment: it try put @ComponentScan(basePackage="com.company.app") still not give me null

Comment: Share your springConfig.xml, CsvService , and QueWorker  java class. You must have configured something incorrec.

Comment: i think i found workaround for the problem thanks :D